# How to validate AngularJS form input while is using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have a form which has input fields that is dynamically built using ng-repeat. How I can validate these fields are greater than another input field. Please look at this sample code.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-init="weekDays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday','thursday', 'friday', 'saturday','sunday']">
    <h1>Fun with Fields and ngModel</h1>
    <p>days: {{weekDays}}</p>
    <h3>Binding to each element directly:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="weekday in weekDays">
        Value: {{weekday}}
        {{day='day_'+weekday; ""}}
        <input name="{{day}}" ng-model="val">                         
    </div>
    <div>
      Number to validate : <input name="numToValidate">
    </div>
</body>
```

I am very new to angularJS and still learning. However I couldn't able to think through this simple validation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html [**form**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) element with min attribute to check validity

```
<input name="{{day}}" ng-model="weekday.val" min="{{numToValidate}}">
```

you will need seperate model for each of your inputs in your ng-repeat therefore I changed your ng-model with the following

```
ng-model="weekday.val"
```

if you do not want to use form you can check the validity of your value with ng-blur directive (triggered when input loses focus).

html

```
<input name="{{day}}" ng-model="weekday.val" ng-blur="checkValid(weekday.val)">
```

js

```
$scope.checkValid = function(value){
    if(value  > $scope.numToValidate){
        alert("please enter a valid number");
    }
}
```

Comment: How to dynamically write validation using the index of elements in the controller?

Comment: Thanks for update. How to do the same on click of a button outside of ng-repeat?

Comment: use ng-click to call your checkValid function

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<form name="form">
    <div ng-repeat="weekday in weekDays">
        Value: {{weekday}}
        {{day='day_'+weekday; ""}}
        <input name="{{day}}" ng-model="val" required>                         
    </div>
    <div>
      Number to validate : <input name="numToValidate" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
if($scope.form.$valid){
    // You can write your code here what you want to do after validate.
}
```

Comment: How to dynamically write validation using the index of elements?